# Spring Boot Not Invoking SecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I setup a springboot application and am trying to get basic user logins setup. From everything I have researched, having the @Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity tags are enough to alert Spring about your class which overrides its configurations (With a @Bean method returning a SecurityFilterChain). However, when running the application, it still uses the DefaultSecurityFilterChain and wants me to login with "user" and autogenerated password that is dumped in the console. I'm not sure what I'm missing to get Spring to recognize my SecurityConfig. However I don't get any System.out/log.info messages when running (other than the main method's Hello World), and it doesn't recognize users from the UserDetailsService.

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ArchlandsUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In securityFilterChain");   
        
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("archlands/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll())
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

UserDetailsService

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ArchlandsUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        String cleanedUsername = ArchlandsInputSanitizer.clean(username);
        log.info("User " + cleanedUsername + " is attempting to access the Archlands.");
        System.out.println("User " + cleanedUsername + " is attempting to access the Archlands.");
        
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        UserDto user = userService.findById(cleanedUsername);
        
        if (user == null) {
            log.error("No user exists with user id: " + cleanedUsername);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user exists with user id: " + cleanedUsername);
        }
        
        if (user.getStatus().equals("Active")) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < user.getRoles().length; i++) {
            if (user.getRoles()[i].equals(Role.DM_ROLE)) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_DM"));
            }
        }
        
        log.info("User: " + cleanedUsername + " has authorities: " + grantedAuthorities.toString());
        
        return new User(user.getId(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
    
}
```

Console Output
[image]

Comment: Sharing a minimum reproducible example of you problem might get you the solution faster. Also, post your logs as text, not as an image, even if it's long. An image is not searchable and is much harder to analyze.

Comment: @S. Cannon, could you provide some context about package structure and how you're using @ComponentScan?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)` annotation to **SecurityConfig** class above `@Configuration` annotation. So, your security configuration becomes higher precedence than the default configuration. Also, you may think add `@Bean` annotation to  **ArchlandsUserDetailsService**, in case to be sure it is properly registered.

Comment: I added both of those annotations, though neither seemed to have an impact on the console output nor on the default login page credentials that are accepted. Also, while I'm still a novice at the security configurations, I haven't seen anywhere that mentions to use Bean with UserDetails loadUserByUsername. From what I've seen, since we are implementing the UserDetailsService, we need to overwrite it's method with our own. I have no idea about the SecurityConfig class still though.

Comment: Be sure that your SecurityConfig class is being scanned and registered by the Spring context.
Also, check that the UserDto object returned by your UserService has the correct values, and that the clean() method in ArchlandsInputSanitizer is not altering the username in an unexpected way.
You can make the SecurityConfig class a priority by using @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE).

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly, the `System.out.println("In securityFilterChain")` in SecurityConfig doesn't get printed. If that's the case, the problem is that the SecurityConfig Configuration doesn't get picked up by Spring.

If you don't use custom *@ComponentScan*-s, check your main Spring class' (the one that is annotated with *@SpringBootApplication*) package - it should be at least the same package level, as your SecurityConfig. Eg.

If your @SpringBootApplication is in package:

```
org.dummy.app.SpringBootApp
```

Then the Security config should be under the org.dummy.app package, like:

```
org.dummy.app.SecurityConfig
```

or like:

```
org.dummy.app.config.SecurityConfig
```